# Change cell frame color in stylesheet

Tags: output-formatting, color, stylesheet

I am trying to make a custom stylesheet, but I am not able to get rid of the cell frame color from the base stylesheet. In particular, I have:

[image]

I have changed the background color of the cell to LightGray. However, an orange frame remains. How do I get rid of this orange frame?

Comment: Add there `CellFrame->None` or `CellFrameColor->None`.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I am new to stylesheets, where should I add this? I've been using the Format menu for modifications.

Comment: In `EditStylesheet..` item. Take a look at `tutorial/WorkingWithStylesheets` too.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work by using the Notebook command and avoiding the whole EditStylesheet interface. Either I have a bug in my version or its non-trivial to find our where to put this in the EditStylesheet...

Comment: This is a menu item which you have to click. If you want to do this programatically you have to use SetOtions StyleDefinitions etc. Read this tutorial. It should explain a lot.

Comment: "using the Notebook command" -- what do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To work with Stylesheets proficiently you need to be able to edit Style [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell.html) code directly, not only make changes via the menus.  While in most cases you can perform the same actions via the Option Inspector there is always a layer of abstraction between you and the code.

After opening the editor via **Format** > **Edit Stylesheet ...** you should see something like:

[image]
If the Style you wish to modify is not present you need to first create a Cell for it.  This is done most conveniently using the **Choose a style** dropdown or by entering the exact Style name without quotation marks in the **Enter a style name :** field and pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Once you have a Style Cell like this:
[image]
you can click on it and use **Cell** > **Show Expression** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in Windows) to reveal:

```
Cell[StyleData["Section"]]
```

It is that Cell data that you need to edit to take full control of the Style.  Options for the Style are given as options for `Cell`.  So for example editing it to read:

```
Cell[StyleData["Section"],
 CellFrame -> 0
]
```

will disable the Cell frame present on the Section style of the StandardReport base which we are modifying.

See also: [`StyleData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleData.html), [`MenuSortingValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MenuSortingValue.html), [`MenuCommandKey`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MenuCommandKey.html).

Comment: Ah, fantastic. The part I was really confused about was how to "show expression". I missed that when looking through the tutorial (it should be the focal point of the tutorial!)

Comment: @JeffDror Glad I could help! :-)